# multiple users connecting to sql server

Tags: javascript, sql-server, node.js

I am using Node js express to connect to a remote SQL Server. It retrieves data from the server and plots a bar graph. I am using the following packages

```
"body-parser": "^1.15.1",
"d3": "^3.5.17",
"express": "^4.13.4",
"jquery": "^2.2.4",
"jsdom": "^9.2.1",
"mssql": "^3.3.0",
"require": "^2.4.20"
```

I have a HTML login page with input fields. The input is POSTED to /user through ajax. This is the code I use to show the user if the credentials he provided were correct.

```
app.post('/user', function (req, res, body) {
uid = req.body.uid;
pwd = req.body.pwd;
 config = 'Server={IPv4 of server};Database=DbName;Uid=domain\\' + uid + ';Pwd=' + pwd;
 dbConn = new sql.Connection(config);

dbConn.connect().then(function () {                                         

    var request = new sql.Request(dbConn);
    // alert

}).catch(function (err) {
   //  alert
});
});
```

where Uid and Pwd are the login credentials of the users. For all users who have access to the database, the connection is etablished and the graph is displayed.

This is the code that gathers data required for the graphs and sends it to a HTML page

```
app.get('/re', function (req, res) {


dbConn.connect().then(function () {                                         //using promises instead of callbacks(onceconnect() is done), then go to then()

    var request = new sql.Request(dbConn);

    request.query("select * from books;").then(function (recordSet) {         //once query is executed, then go to then()

        res.send(recordSet);
        dbConn.close();                                                      //close connection
    }).catch(function (err) {

        console.log(err);
        dbConn.close();
    });
}).catch(function (err) {

    console.log(err);
});

});
```

The following problem arises when multiple users on different PCs try to access it at the same time.

1.) If user A has logged in and is viewing the graphs, user B can also view the same graph without logging in by simply browsing to that page

2.) If user A changes the query to view only a subset of the graph, user B is forced to see that change upon refresh

3.)When userA closes the connection i.e, logs off , user B cannot see the page anymore.

It seems there is only one connection being established. Irrespective of whether user B has logged in or not,he sees the page.

When user A,B use it serially(one after the other),it works as desired.

Please help me. I have absolutely no clue on how to proceed further.

EDIT 1: all this is happening because my variable config can at a time hold only one UID and PWD. So, user B can view graphs even when he is not logged in through user A's credentials

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer to this - The problem was because I had not used sessions in my code. When I began using express-session in node js, it worked as expected as in [Session management in Nodejs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34838983/session-management-in-nodejs)