# What happens with the state in a React isomorphic App

Tags: reactjs, isomorphic-javascript

I am building an isomorphic app with React that must support users without JS.

I am new in this technology and I have a basic doubt:
The server can store the components states to emulate what React does in the client-side?

I imagine this flow when the user dont have JS:

1. The user click a button and send a request to the server.
2. The server recovers the state of the app and makes changes in it.
3. The components listen this changes and are rendered again.

Is it correct?

Comment: In essence, React in your case would run only on the server to produce static HTML pages -- which is comparable to rendering HTML with, say, PHP: the server puts the page together, then hurls it towards the client, fire and forget. You will navigate between static pages using `<a>` elements. What "real" isomorphic React apps do is that they pre-render a static page only once, and then inject into the pre-rendered markup to provide dynamic client-side behavior afterwards. You are correct that you can persist app state between calls, but this requires some kind of session management.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you're using react-router :

The server aims to initialize your state, to provide it the default minimum values necessary to make your application work while getting an url.

For example, if you have an application in which you want to display a user list, let say on /users URL, when you'll send **your first request**, the server will store the users in the react state.

After that **first load**, you'll be working on the client side using react-router, and making XHR request.

However, if you refresh your page, the process will start again : **first load initializing the state** and then client side navigation.

EDIT : Explanations =>

When you want to use react on the server, this means that you use a Nodejs server. The fact is that react-dom provides a method called renderToString that transform a react jsx component into standard HTML.

This aims to load **the first call faster**

*Why ?*

When you load a "big" JS application on the client, you have some delay time, the time your browser needs to download your JS bundle.

Server side rendering aims to avoid that behaviour, or at least, to gives the feeling that the app starts faster.

---

In no case you can only use react, even if you use your server side renders. *Why ?* . Because your events on buttons, or asynchronous load on client, or keypress are in JS language.

Comment: Thanks for the response! But what if the client  dont have JS ?

Comment: You can't use react without javascript

Comment: @Margin Actually, it is my understanding that you can render HTML pages on the server side, just as you would using, say, PHP. Isn't that so?

Comment: I m going to edit my answer to help you understand a bit better

Comment: *"After that first load, you'll be working on the client side using react-router, and making XHR request."* -- not if the client has no JS, as it is stated in the question. In this case, all the client has is the HTML received from the server. In this regard, it is always a "first request". I believe this should be possible -- not necessarily _feasible_ with React, but certainly possible.

Comment: Thats exactly what I want  @John Weisz, a React Isomorphic app that can run with and without JS, in case of no JS in the client, a Node.js server must do the work, but I don't understand how it must deal with the state.

Comment: @SebastiánDelleDonne -- You will need a way to distinguish between clients _on the server_, and _rebuild_ or _obtain_ the state _associated with that client_. Sure, you can keep the app state on the server in an object, but how do you determine _which client it is meant for_? You are having multiple clients affecting the _same object_. This problem, determining server state based on _which_ client made the request, is classically called session management, and I'm sure it is already implemented on NodeJS in dozens of ways.

Comment: @SebastiánDelleDonne -- You might want to look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34838983/session-management-in-nodejs